# Exporting multiple csv files using For loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, read.csv

This is the code I have used ,but I do get all csv files ,but with just one single row with column names , no other data ...Can you pls tell me what is wrong with my code ?

```
m<-length(unique(rd_1$mall))
dataframe.list<-list()

for(i in 1:m){
dataframe.list[[i]] <- subset(rd_1, mall==i)
write.csv(dataframe.list[[i]], file = 
paste0("C:/Users/yogesh/Desktop/Work/Analysis/","mall_",i, 
".csv"), row.names = TRUE)
}
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
y <- length(unique(population$year))
dataframe.list <- list()


for (i in 1:y){
  dataframe.list[[i]] <- subset(population, year == i)
  write.csv(dataframe.list[[i]], file = paste0("year_", i), row.names = TRUE)
}
read.csv("year_1", row.names = 1)
# [1] country    year       population
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your first line in the loop:

```
dataframe.list[[i]] <- subset(rd_1, mall == i)
```

You are looking for those rows in `rd_1` where the value for `mall` is `1`. Given your first line, I don't think that is what you want. Try creating a new vector, maybe name it `malls`. Set that to `unique(rd1$mall)`. Then as you subset, use `mall == malls[i]`, instead of `mall == i`.

```
malls <-unique(rd_1$mall)
m <- length(malls)
dataframe.list<-list()

for(i in 1:m){
dataframe.list[[i]] <- subset(rd_1, mall==malls[i])
write.csv(dataframe.list[[i]], file = 
paste0("C:/Users/yogesh/Desktop/Work/Analysis/","mall_",i, 
".csv"), row.names = TRUE)
}
```

We can reproduce your problem and the solution with `population`, the built in data set. Notice, just a side note to improve your code. When you loop through `1:m`, or here, `1:y`, you know how many objects you're going to go through. Allocate the size of the list. Here it's `dataframe.list <- vector("list", y)`

Problem:

```
y <- length(unique(population$year))
dataframe.list <- vector("list", y)


for (i in 1:y){
  dataframe.list[[i]] <- subset(population, year == i)
  write.csv(dataframe.list[[i]], file = paste0("year_", i), row.names = TRUE)
}
read.csv("year_1")
[1] X          country    year       population
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Solution:

```
years <- unique(population$year)
y <- length(years)
dataframe.list <- vector("list", y)


for (i in 1:y){
  dataframe.list[[i]] <- subset(population, year == years[i])
  write.csv(dataframe.list[[i]], file = paste0("year_", i), row.names = TRUE)
}
head(read.csv("year.1", row.names = 1))
         country year population
1    Afghanistan 1995   17586073
2        Albania 1995    3357858
3        Algeria 1995   29315463
4 American Samoa 1995      52874
5        Andorra 1995      63854
6         Angola 1995   12104952
```

Comment: @YogeshKumar you're welcome :)  Welcome to stack overflow!  When someone answers your question, select it as the answer. Once you have the voting privilege you should also upvote useful answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers